# Textures split up when using "Data Transfer" modifier

Tags: texturing, uv

I have transferred a texture across objects using the "Data Transfer" modifier. But when the texture is on the new object, the textures are split apart strangely (along the seams). How can I fix this?
Because I'm planning to sell this object, **I've uploaded a photoscan file with the same problem (it always seems to happen.)**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your file doesn't have the textures packed.

Comment: Thanks for notifying me, I just fixed it!

Comment: It looks like the data transfer isn't generating UV seams fsr. Maybe you could bake with clean uv's instead of using data transfer.

Comment: Yeah, baking worked for me.

Comment: Can you explain the process? I'm not quite getting what your saying.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Delete Data Transfer modifier.
- Create a UV map.
- Create a new image in the image editor.
  [image: new img]
- In the low poly object's material nodes, click the blue thing to make it a separate material from the original object's.[image: blue thing]
- Unlink the image from the Principled BSDF and select the new image.
  [image: select img]
- In the original material, plug the texture into the Material Output.
  [image: orig mat]
- Select the original object then the low poly object so that it is active.
- Make sure the disconnected image node is selected in the node editor.
  [image: disconnected image node]
- In Properties Editor → Render Properties, set up the Bake section something like this.
  (This section is only available for CPU rendering.)
  [image: bake]
  The Extrusion setting is the one to fiddle with.
- After setting the render samples to a low number (1 worked for me), click Bake.

This should leave you with a nice new image texture that will work with the UV map that you created.

[image: rock]

Comment: When I do everything you said, and try to bake them, I get an error message that reads "No active UV layer found in the object"

Comment: Did you make a uv map?

Comment: Do you mean the thing you named "whoopee"? If that is the case, then yes I did.

Comment: No, a UV map not an image texture. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM

Comment: In other words, what you're asking is: "Did you unwrap your object?"? Because no, I didn't. And if that is what I do, what type of unwrap do I do? Sorry, I'm really not knowledgeable in the area of baking.

Comment: Just go into edit mode and press U then select either _Smart UV Project_ or _Lightmap Pack_ to get a quick and dirty unwrap. To get a _good_ UV map you'll want to manually mark the seams and then use _Unwrap._

Comment: @HISEROD you don't even need the Emission node, just plug image directly into Surface socket of Material Output node

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the data transfer modifier not transferring seams is that the original model didn't have any UV seams marked.

To fix this, select the original model, change to the UV editing layout, and select **Seams From Islands**.
[image: Seams From Islands]

Now, in the data transfer modifier of the low poly model, Switch to Nearest Face Interpolated for best results in this scenario.
[image: Nearest Face Interpolated]

This doesn't yield perfect results, but it does eliminate most of the distortion around seams.
[image: Stretching and Visible Seams]

Also, I wouldn't recommend this solution in a case where the original UV map takes up such a tiny amount of the available texture space.
[image: Ouch]